# Compare the index of 2 string arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to figure out how to reference the index of 2 string arrays.  In the checkAnswer method I can confirm the users input is stored in the capitalArray at index [i] but how do I compare the index of capitalArray[i] == stateArray[i] instead of comparing the strings stored at index [i]

```
        public static void main{ 
        ...

        for (int i = 1; i <=10;  i++){

        System.out.println("What is the capital of " + stateArray[randomQuestion(0)]"?");
        answer = in.nextLine();

        if (checkAnswer(stateArray, capitalArray, answer) == true)
        {
            correct++;
        }
        total = i;
    }
  }

   public static boolean checkAnswer(String[]stateArray, String[]capitalArray, String answer) {

    for (int i = 0; i < stateArray.length; i++) 
    {
        if (capitalArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && capitalArray[i] == stateArray[i])    
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I compare the index of capitalArray[i] == stateArray[i] instead of comparing the strings stored at index [i]" , why do you want to compare index of state and capital?

Comment: If I compare the stateArray[1] = "New York" and capitalArray[1] = "Albany" the program will tell me the answer is wrong even though it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should determine the random state you want to use, keep that index, then check the user's input against the `capitalArray` in the same index.  There's no need to loop through both arrays when checking the answer.

Something like this:

```
index = Random.nextInt(50);  // random number between 0-49

System.out.println("Enter the capital for " + states[index] + ":");
String answer = in.nextLine();


//Precondition: the arrays for the capitals and state must be in the correct order for
//this to work properly
if ( capitals[index].equalsIgnoreCase( answer ) )
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

The `checkAnswer` function you have is comparing `answer` to `capitalArray` and then seeing if `capitalArray[i]` and `stateArray[i]` are the same String.  Of course the latter isn't true.

Comment: Awesome...I had tried something similar to this a few times before but the random index generation kept spitting out 0.  I've got it working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a Hashmap to store capital and state. You are making it complicated by using 2 arrays. Hashmap can have state as key and capital as vaule and now you can easily iterate and check.

Edit:

when you know that capital and state will be at same index then what will you achieve by comparing indexes of 2 arrays? Once you have fond capital in capital array , you are done. No need to check state array.

But i will not recommend array approach.

Edit:

And it will be sufficient to check that both arrays have same length before starting for loop, if at all you want to have that verification

Comment: I have to use 2 parallel arrays for the assignment.  The quiz will ask the user to name the capital city of a randomly generated state from the stateArray.  Then I have to use a method to check the answer and make sure the answer given matches the same index in each array.  If I try to compare the two arrays using the .equals() approach the return will be false ie... stateArray[1] = New York ... capitalArray[1] = Albany

Comment: My understanding is, that you are storing capitals in capital array and states in statearray. Each state capital combination is stored at same index . Am i right ?

Comment: correct each state / capital combination are at the same index in the 2 arrays

Comment: So when you know that capital and state will be at same index then what will you achieve by comparing indexes of 2 arrays? Once you have fond capital in capital array , you are done. No need to check state array.

Comment: In the check answer method I'm looping thru the capitalArray to see if the users answer matches any entries.  If I leave it at that the answer will be correct for any state the user is asked about.  Once I know the user has entered a valid capital name I need to see if the index of the capital name is the same as the index of the state name.  If that makes sense...sorry I'm struggling with arrays.

Comment: When you create 2 arrays of state and capital then you ensure that same indices in both arrays contain right pair of state/capital. All the hard work has been done there. By checking index in state array in your approach you you are just ensuring that an index at that level exist in state array which is not really helping. How about checking that before arrays have same length before starting for loop? I think that should do the job